# bash shell gives weird result when directory exists vs not

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Alright, I've wasted a full day on a script that was behaving very oddly.  I have found out something that I can't explain.

```
ny-02-ops:~$ rm -fr roles
ny-02-ops:~$ echo role[blerk]
role[blerk]
ny-02-ops:~$ echo role[sugar]
role[sugar]
ny-02-ops:~$ mkdir roles
ny-02-ops:~$ echo role[blerk]
role[blerk]
```

Here's  my "WTF" moment

```
ny-02-ops:~$ echo role[sugar]
roles
ny-02-ops:~$ mkdir roleb
ny-02-ops:~$ echo role[blerk]
roleb
```

I know there's a `bash` guru out there who can explain this, and I would be very grateful to know what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

Square brackets in a glob match one of the characters inside. If a glob with metacharacters (`*`, `[...]`, etc.) matches no filenames then the glob is returned unchanged.

```
echo "role[sugar]"
echo "role[blerk]"
```

Comment: I bet Mike wishes he'd asked you that a little earlier in the day! Very cool.

Comment: Which means `echo r[ovaltine][layover][hyperglycemic][sugardaddy]` will return `roles` but  `echo r[gassy][ugtastic][difficult][blovatier]` will just return itself.

Comment: Ohhhhhh.  I was staring at it too long.  Of course!!  (facepalm).  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour of the shell is to expand a glob where possible, otherwise return it unchanged. There are ways to change this behaviour, however.

To expand non-matching globs to an empty string (useful for `for` loops which you may just want to skip if no files match, for example), use `nullglob`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

If the fact that the glob doesn't expand is considered an error, use `failglob`:

```
shopt -s failglob
```

Use `shopt -u` to unset these shell options.